# How can I change the numbering of an order list's items?

Tags: jquery, html, css

We have a simple AJAX application that pings a web service and populates an ordered list element with `<li/>` elements from its results. Each time the operation is started, it clears out the existing `<li/>` elements and repopulates the ordered list.

I've seen various tutorials on css counter operations, but I can't seem to make it work. I think it's because we're clearing the ordered list each time. Can someone give me an idea about how to manually set the list item numbers?

Comment: Can you provide example of your code please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `value="yournumber"` on the list items. From [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html):

```
<ol>
  <li value="30"> makes this list item number 30.
  <li value="40"> makes this list item number 40.
  <li> makes this list item number 41.
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this works for your code, but here's a way to do it with CSS and `counter-reset`

**HTML**

```
<ol id="one">
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
</ol>

<ol id="two">
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something</li>    
</ol>
```

**CSS**

```
#one{
    counter-reset:item;
}
#two{
    counter-reset:item 10; 
}
li:before {
    content: counter(item) ". ";
    counter-increment: item;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/WWtFY/